# PDF file not open in nougat Android

Tags: android, pdf, android-7.0-nougat

I am new in Android and I am facing problem regarding to open PDF file in naught. While in marshmallow and other android version it opens but in nougat it doesn't.

My code is like this

```
private void CopyReadAssets()
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "Induction.pdf");
        try
        {
            copyFile(assetManager.open("Induction.pdf"), file);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                //intent.setDataAndType(getUri(file), type);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.econnect.team.PdfContentProvider/"+"Induction.pdf");
               // Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".PdfContentProvider", file);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, type);

            } else {
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
                Log.e("Uri ", " "+ Uri.fromFile(file));
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

        }catch (FileUriExposedException ex){
            Log.e("Uri ", "exception: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Toast.makeText(Menus.this, "No activity found to open this attachment.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, File f) throws IOException
    {
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                out = openFileOutput(f.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            }
            else {
                out = openFileOutput(f.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            }
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("copy file", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Did anybody face this problem like this

Comment: because you never put file into your FileProvider and you are passing meaningless uri

Comment: @Selvin How to do that can you please share code?

Comment: The code is in the example from official android's documentation I do not see the point for repeating it here on SO (especially when it was reapeat enough times already)

Comment: @Muju did you find any solution for it, because after spending whole day I am unable to read pdf in Nougat, but it runs perfect on Marshmellow.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open some file stored in application's internal storage with some third party app, then you should use **FileProvider** for getting the uri for the file. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: @Muju but the code that you have posted didn't use FileProvider

Comment: PdfContentProvider is the file provider.

Answer (score 0):

If You Are Using android-N (i.e API 24 Above)
Do Like this.:

```
    try {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                File f = new File(yourPath);

                                Uri uri = null;

                                // Above Compile SDKversion: 25 -- Uri.fromFile Not working
                                // So you have to use Provider
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                 uri = Uri.parse("content://com.econnect.team.PdfContentProvider/"+"Induction.pdf");

                                // Add in case of if We get Uri from fileProvider.
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                }else{
                                    uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                                }

                                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                                startActivity(intent);
}catch(Exeption e){
    e.printstacktrace();
}
```

You can Also Use Your File Provider

```
 Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".PdfContentProvider", file);
```

Or Use it Like:

```
 uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
                                            ".provider", file);
```

instead

```
uri = Uri.parse("content://com.econnect.team.PdfContentProvider/"+"Induction.pdf");
```

Which You erliar Created

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete way to read pdf file in Android 7.0 or less:

**Step-1:**
First of all, place your pdf file in assets folder like the following screenshot.
[image: Placing pdf file in assets folder]

**Step-2:**
Now go to build.gradle file and add following lines:

```
repositories {
maven {
    url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
}
```

}

and then under dependencies add the following line and sync:

```
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:provider:0.4.3'
```

**Step-3:**
Now add a new java file which should extend from `FileProvider` Like in my case file name is `LegacyCompatFileProvider` and code inside of it.

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

import com.commonsware.cwac.provider.LegacyCompatCursorWrapper;

public class LegacyCompatFileProvider extends FileProvider {
  @Override
  public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    return(new LegacyCompatCursorWrapper(super.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)));
  }
}
```

**Step-4:**
Create a folder named `"xml"` under `"res"` folder. (If the folder is already there then no need to create). Now add a `providers_path.xml` file, in `xml` folder. Here is the screenshot:
[image: Place of provider_path xml file]

Inside file add following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="stuff" />
</paths>
```

**Step-5:**
Now go to `AndroidManifest.xml` file and following lines in `<application></application>` tag:

```
<provider
            android:name="LegacyCompatFileProvider"
            android:authorities="REPLACE_IT_WITH_PACKAGE_NAME"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

**Step-6:**
Now go to the Activity class from where you want to load pdf and add following 1 line and these 2 methods:

```
private static final String AUTHORITY="REPLACE_IT_WITH_PACKAGE_NAME";

static private void copy(InputStream in, File dst) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(dst);
        byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len=in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

    private  void LoadPdfFile(String fileName){

        File f = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName + ".pdf");

        if (!f.exists()) {
            AssetManager assets=getAssets();

            try {
                copy(assets.open(fileName + ".pdf"), f);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("FileProvider", "Exception copying from assets", e);
            }
        }

        Intent i=
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, f));

        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
```

Now call `LoadPdfFile` method and pass your file name without `.pdf` like in my case `"chapter-0"` and it will open pdf file in pdf reader.